# Замена части кода во время работы программы

Tags: python

Есть массив:

```
namesofperson = []
namesofperson.append("Ярослав Мудрый")
namesofperson.append("Николай II")
namesofperson.append("Екатерина I")
namesofperson.append("Иван IV")
namesofperson.append("Александр I")
namesofperson.append("Пётр I")
namesofperson.append("Александр II")
namesofperson.append("Александр III")
namesofperson.append("Владимир Ильич Ленин")
namesofperson.append("Иосиф Сталин")
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы я выбрал, допустим, 0-й элемент, изменил его и изменения сохранились в массиве и после перезапуска программы тоже?

Хранить данные в файле не вариант.

Comment: В чём же вы желаете хранить, если не в файле?

Comment: После запуска, программа хранит данные в оперативной памяти. После того, как программа завершается, если не ошибаюсь, сборщик мусора, удаляет из памяти то, что в нём было записано.

У вас есть несколько вариантов: либо использовать файл, либо использовать базу данных. По другому, скорее всего, не получится.

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik база данных хранит свои данные в файлах ;)

Comment: @andreymal, нету баз данных, которые хранят данные в оперативной памяти?

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik ну разве что если автора устроит потеря данных после перезагрузки компьютера, на которой база. Ну или держать два компьютера (или больше) с двумя базами (или больше) и репликацией данных между ними и неодновременной перезагрузкой, но это уже извращениями попахивает

Comment: Хорошо, Допустим хранить в файлах. Можете привести пример, как записать массив в файл и как менять и добавлять элементы в этот файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Записи в файл кажись не избежать. Пример записи в файл и повторного считывания:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
w = ["Йцукенг", "Фывапр"]
with open("./test.txt", "w") as f1:
    f1.writelines("\n".join(w))

with open("./test.txt", "r") as f2:
    text = f2.read()
for i in text.split("\n"):
    print i

# Йцукенг
# Фывапр
```

Comment: Вместо 2 строк

    `text = f2.read()`
`for i in text.split("\n"):`

возможно просто написать

    `for i in f2:`

Answer (score 1):

Стандартный модуль [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pickle.html) позволяет сохранять/загружать в/из бинарного файла любые Python объекты любой сложности.

Пример:

```
In [13]: import pickle

In [14]: with open("d:/temp/data.pkl", 'wb') as f:
    ...:     pickle.dump(namesofperson, f)
    ...:

In [15]: with open("d:/temp/data.pkl", 'rb') as f:
    ...:     items = pickle.load(f)
    ...:

In [16]: print(items)
['Ярослав Мудрый', 'Николай II', 'Екатерина I', 'Иван IV', 'Александр I', 'Пётр I', 'Александр II', 'Александр III', 'Владимир Ильич Ленин', 'Иосиф С
талин']
```